# Replace Subselect for something more efficient

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query which takes a long time, partly because the number of records in the table excedd 500 000 records, but the join I have to use slows it down quite a lot, at least to my beliefs

```
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT H1.DateCompteur, CASE WHEN (h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie > 0)         
THEN h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie ELSE 0 END AS Compte, H1.IdMachine
FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H1 INNER JOIN
     dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H2 ON H1.IdMachine = H2.IdMachine AND H2.DateCompteur =
     (SELECT MAX(DateCompteur) AS Expr1
        FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS HS
       WHERE (DateCompteur < H1.DateCompteur) AND (H1.IdMachine = IdMachine))
ORDER BY H1.DateCompteur DESC
```

The order by is important since I need only the most recent informations. I tried using the ID field in my sub select since they are ordred by date but could not detect any significant improvement.

```
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT H1.DateCompteur, CASE WHEN (h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie > 0)         
THEN h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie ELSE 0 END AS Compte, H1.IdMachine
FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H1 INNER JOIN
     dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H2 ON H1.IdMachine = H2.IdMachine AND H2.ID =
     (SELECT MAX(ID) AS Expr1
        FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS HS
       WHERE (ID < H1.ID) AND (H1.IdMachine = IdMachine))
ORDER BY H1.DateCompteur DESC
```

the table I use look a little like this (I got much more columns but they are unused in this query).

```
ID bigint
IdMachine bigint
cSortie bigint
DateCompteur datetime
```

I think that if I could get rid of the sub select, my query would run much faster but I can't really find a way to do so. What I really want to do is to find the previous row with the same IdMachine so that I can calculate the difference between the two cSortie values. The case in the query is because something it's reseted to 0 and in this case, I want to return 0 instead of a negative value.

So my question is this : Can I do better than what I already have ??? I plan to put this in a view if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
WITH T as
(
  SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT H1.DateCompteur, H1.cSortie as cSortie1, H1.IdMachine,
  (
        SELECT TOP 1 H2.cSortie
        FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur H2
        WHERE (H2.DateCompteur < H1.DateCompteur) AND (H1.IdMachine = H2.IdMachine)
        ORDER BY H2.DateCompteur DESC   
  ) as cSortie2
  FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H1
  ORDER BY H1.DateCompteur DESC 
)

select DateCompteur, 
       CASE WHEN (cSortie1 - cSortie2 > 0)         
            THEN cSortie1 - cSortie2 
            ELSE 0 END 
            AS Compte, 
       IdMachine
FROM T
```

Comment: I tried it, it's actually better most of the time by about 2 secondes (3-4 for yours compared to 6-7 for mine). However, some of the time, it's actually slower. I don't really know why this is happening though. I'm thinking that maybe I could try to insert the linked ID when I insert the record. The stress of finding the ID (which will always be MAX(ID) where IdMachine = @IdMachine)  might be less than trying to find it during the querying phase. I just don't know how faster it will really get.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try CTE's (common table expressions) with windowing functions (ROW_NUMBER):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,IdMachine,cSortie,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.IdMachine ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [ROW] 
    FROM T_HistoriqueCompteur h
)
SELECT 
    TOP (10) PERCENT 
        H1.DateCompteur,
        CASE WHEN (h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie > 0) THEN h1.cSortie - h2.cSortie 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS Compte,
        H1.IdMachine
FROM dbo.T_HistoriqueCompteur AS H1 
INNER JOIN CTE cte on cte.idmachine = h1.idmachine and cte.id = h1.id
INNER JOIN CTE h2 on h2.idmachine = cte.idmachine and h2.row + 1 = cte.row
ORDER BY H1.DateCompteur DESC
```